# Wrong direction for curve segememts

Tags: bezier-curves, normals

I'm extremely new to Blender.

I finished most of the body and clothes and I want to work with the hair.
I want to use curves with the hair but upon using curves, the segments (idk what to call them) are in the wrong direction.

[image]
[image]

Lastly this is me trying to tinker with it.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is the "[tilt](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/curves/editing/control_points.html#tilt)" of your control point.

You can change it via the Tilt modal, shortcut <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>, or access it from the sidebar:

[image: tilt value picture]

Comment: So I tried using CTRL T to tilt it and instead of moving like I hoped it would it does move but only on one side. It doesn't tilt the way I would like it to look.
It still looks like all of the segments are hugging to be symmetric to the Y axis rather than the X axis.

Comment: The tilt is a setting tied to control points, not to the entire curve. You have to set the tilt you need on all the control points you want to affect.